# How to trace dynamically loaded libraries with Valgrind?

Tags: shared-libraries, valgrind

I have a process that uses `dlopen` and `dlclose` to load/unload a library. The library has some memory leaks which I want to trace with Valgrind. I tried the following:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libmylibrary.so valgrind --leak-check=full myprogram
```

It doesn't work. I get an undefined symbol error because the library depends on some symbols from the main program. Is there any other way to make the library stay loaded at the end of the program?

Comment: What OS do you use? What do you observe if you do *not* preload?

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I believe this can help someone in the future if he/she stumbles upon it.

You can pass `--keep-debuginfo=yes` parameter to valgrind:

> --keep-debuginfo=<yes|no> [default: no]
>
> When enabled, keep ("archive") symbols and all other debuginfo for unloaded code. This
> allows saved stack traces to include file/line info for code that has been dlclose'd (or
> similar). Be careful with this, since it can lead to unbounded memory use for programs which
> repeatedly load and unload shared objects.
>
> Some tools and some functionalities have only limited support for archived debug info.
> Memcheck fully supports it. Generally, tools that report errors can use archived debug info to
> show the error stack traces. The known limitations are: Helgrind's past access stack trace of a
> race condition is does not use archived debug info. Massif (and more generally the xtree Massif
> output format) does not make use of archived debug info. Only Memcheck has been (somewhat) tested
> with --keep-debuginfo=yes, so other tools may have unknown limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the dlclose() in your testing program so that the shared object's code segment would be kept in your process'es memory mapping table. Then when valgrind's finds any leaks caused by this shared object, it could find the symbol names from the process's memory mapping table.

If you call the dlclose(), the dl library may unload the shared object from the process's memory space, then the valgrind will fail to resolve the address to a meaningful symbol name.

Besides, use LD_PRELOAD= for loading the library with debugging information.

Comment: I cannot control whether to call dlclose. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: This is an old thread I writes as much as I can remember. I wrote a test program that directly call dlopen for loading my test code and using Valgrind for checking memory leaks. Directly call the dlopen is for preventing memory leak caused by OS triggered dll unload.

Comment: For rest of the detail, maybe you can check this example: https://gist.github.com/tailriver/30bf0c943325330b7b6a

Comment: Thank you for the reply!